# vb.net - How to open an application from any drive

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a "control panel" style application with buttons that open applications. I want to go through all drive letters (A-Z) in the default install location. For example, if `CCleaner` is installed at `M:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe`, is there a way to make the button also check all drive letters `A-Z:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe`

Code Snippit

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click

    Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    Try
        proc = Process.Start("C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner64.exe", "")
    Catch ex As Exception
        proc = Process.Start("D:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner64.exe", "")
    End Try
        ' ... and so on
End Sub
```

EDIT: I have looked at [Getting a list of logical drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781905/getting-a-list-of-logical-drives) before, and I'm sure my answer is somewhere in there, but very confused on how to directly implement it with in my code.

EDIT: For Richard

```
    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click

    Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()

    For Each c In "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
        proc = Process.Start(c + ":\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner64.exe")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to get the available drive letter?

Comment: @RichardBaluyut - I want when the button is clicked, it looks at ALL drive letters to that path A-Z:\ProgramFiles\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe

Comment: `..but very confused on how to directly implement it with in my code` Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives) and check the examples there, they're available in both C# and VB.

Comment: I tried you code, and the error is if the driver is exist or not.

Comment: This isn't just about getting the list of drives. The OP has no clue what to do once he has the list.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, however this is how I would do it.
First of all, there is no need to search from `A-Z` as thats what [DriveInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=netframework-4.7.2) is for.
Secondly, why would you want to add every program to your control panel program, like why would you want the [Mobile Plan](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/mobile-plans/9nblggh5pnb1?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) Application in there?
 Forgive me if I have misunderstood your question, however it kinda sounds like you want to search through each file in the programs folder and add their exes to your application?? like dynamically add items?
However with that being said, here is how I achieved what you are asking for in a console application, copy the functions and methods where needed

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
'' List Of The Programs We Will Want
'' Key Is The Program Folder Name,
'' Value Is The Programs Name
Private Property Programs As Dictionary(Of String, String)

'' Get Program Files Path
Private ReadOnly Program_Files As String = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramW6432%")

'' Create A String Builder
Private Property ConstructedPath As StringBuilder

Sub Main()

    '' Create The String Builder Object Above
    ConstructedPath = New StringBuilder()

    '' Programs We Wish To Use
    '' Why would you want to use them all
    '' eg Calculator doesnt really belong in
    '' the control panel
    Programs = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
        {"CCleaner", "CCleaner64"}
    }

    '' Get All Fixed Disk Drives
    '' No Need To Search From A-Z
    Dim diskDrives As IEnumerable(Of DriveInfo) = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(Function(d) d.DriveType = DriveType.Fixed)

    '' Loop through each drive And attempt to
    '' run the application
    For Each drive As DriveInfo In diskDrives

        For Each program As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In Programs
            '' path to the executable
            ConstructedPath.AppendFormat(String.Format($"{drive.Name}{Program_Files.Split("\"c).Last()}\{program.Key}\{program.Value}.exe"))

            '' If the program exits, than lets attempt to
            '' execute it
            If ProgramExist(ConstructedPath.ToString()) Then
                '' boolean for if needed to check status later on
                Dim executed As Boolean = ExecuteProgram(ConstructedPath.ToString())
            End If

            '' Clear String Builder For The Next Loop
            ConstructedPath.Clear()
        Next
    Next

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' If the Given Path Is Valid,
''' We Will Attempt To Execute It.
''' Executes The Given Path
''' </summary>
''' <param name="path"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Private Function ExecuteProgram(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
    Dim isRunning As Boolean = False

    Try
        Process.Start(path)
    Catch ex As Exception
        '' Something Happened
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)
    Finally

        For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()

            If p.ProcessName.Contains(path.Split("\"c).Last()) Then
                isRunning = True
            End If
        Next
    End Try

    Return isRunning
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Validate The Given Path
''' </summary>
''' <param name="path"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Private Function ProgramExist(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
    Return System.IO.File.Exists(path)
End Function

End Module
```

I added a function that will check if the path is valid, if not the process will not execute and if it is valid, well it will.
I used a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) to hold the values, `key` is used for the programs folder name and `value` is used for the programs name, yes if you have multiple programs you want to execute in the same folder,
 you will need to write another function or even use a [List String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/) as the `value` instead.
As for creating a button dynamically, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604297/dynamic-created-buttons-vb-net-with-loop) post

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click 
    Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process
    Dim allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While proc Is Nothing AndAlso i < allDrives.Length
        Try
            proc = Process.Start(allDrives(i).Name & "Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner64.exe", "")
        Catch ex As Exception
            proc = Nothing
        End Try
        i+=1
    End While
End Subd
```

The real question for me is **why** you would do this. It just doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()

    For Each c In "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
        If IO.Directory.Exists(c + ":\") Then
                proc = Process.Start(c + ":\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
        Else
        End If
    Next
```

Try this, it works for me.